# "All retracts are closed" as separation axiom

Tags: gn.general-topology

The starting point of this question is the fact that any retract of a $T_2$-space is closed.

Let's say a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is $T_{\textrm{rc}}$ if all retracts of $X$ are closed.

All $T_{\textrm{rc}}$-spaces are $T_1$, because singletons are always retracts, and a space is $T_1$ if and only if all singleton subsets are closed. So we have $T_2 \implies T_{\textrm{rc}}\implies T_1$.

The second implication is not an equivalence: Consider $(\omega,\mathcal{P}_{\text{cf}}(\omega))$ where $\mathcal{P}_{\text{cf}}(\omega) = \{\emptyset\}\cup \{U\subseteq \omega: \omega\setminus U \text{ is finite}\}$. Let $S$ be the set of even numbers and $r:\omega \to S$ be defined by $2n\mapsto 2n$ and $2n+1 \mapsto 2n$ for all $n\in\omega$.  Then $S$ is a retract of $(\omega,\mathcal{P}_{\text{cf}}(\omega))$ but it is not closed. So the implication $T_{\textrm{rc}}\implies T_1$ is not an equivalence.

**Question**: Do we have $T_2 \Leftrightarrow T_{\text{rc}}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be a compactly generated Hausdorff space which fails to be locally compact at precisely one point. Now take the Alexandroff compactification of $X$, adding exactly one new point, whose neighborhoods have compact complement in $X$. The new space is not Hausdorff, but has the property that it is compact, and each compact subspace is closed. In general the image of a compact space is compact, and hence each retract of the new space is a closed subspace of itself.

Comment: How do you know each compact subspace is closed without the Hausdorff property?

Comment: Thanks Steven, nice catch! We should also assume $X$ is compactly generated, i.e. $A$ is closed in $X$ iff $A \cap C$ is closed in $X$ for each compact $C \subset X$.

Comment: To see why we must also assume $X$ is compactly generated, let $X$ be the plane, but refine the usual topology so that each countable set is closed. Then no infinite subset of $X$ is compact. However if $Y$ is the Alexandroff compactifictation then each subset of $Y$ which contains $\infty$ is compact. In particular $Y \setminus 0$ is compact but not closed in $Y$.

Comment: A couple other notes for posterity: local compactness need only fail at *at least* one point to break T2 in the compactification, not *precisely*. The proof that compactly generated KC spaces produce KC compactifications in general is Thm 5 of https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316017 We investigated some of this at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434451/

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be the [rationals with their subspace topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000027), and $X^+=X\cup\{\infty\}$ be [its one-point compactification](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000029).

Because $X$ is not locally compact, $X^+$ is not $T_2$.

The space $X^+$ has the property $T_{kc}$, that is, [all compact subsets are closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524171).

We now show that all compact $T_{kc}$ spaces $K$ are $T_{rc}$. Let $A$ be a retract of $K$. Then $A$ is a continuous image of $K$, and therefore compact. By $T_{kc}$, $A$ is closed.

Therefore $X^+$ is a $T_{rc}$ space which is not $T_2$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, just a possibly useful observation.

**Theorem:** If the property $T_\mathrm{rc}$ is preserved by finite products then any $T_\mathrm{rc}$ space is $T_2$.

*Proof.*
Suppose $T_\mathrm{rc}$ is preserved by finite products and $X$ is $T_\mathrm{rc}$. By assumption $X \times X$ is also $T_\mathrm{rc}$, therefore its diagonal $\Delta_X = \{(x,y) \in X \times X \mid x = y\}$ is closed, as it is a retract of $X \times X$ by the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x,x)$. But a space is $T_2$ iff its diagonal is closed, so $X$ is $T_2$.

Comment: You seem to have proved the right-to-left direction twice and not proved the converse.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I deleted the fake news and alternative facts.