# A "simple" space with closed retracts but non-unique sequential limits

Tags: gn.general-topology, separation-axioms

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434451/all-retracts-are-closed-and-all-compacts-are-closed) asking how **KC** ("Kompacts are Closed") and **RC** ("Retracts are Closed") are distinct has some good discussion, including a [now-published](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v62/tp62014p1.pdf) example by Banakh and Stelmakh which is RC but not KC. An earlier revision of their paper had an example which was actually not **US** ("Unique Sequential limits", weaker than KC), but was revised so the version in print was US. I've read [that earlier revision](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12579v3) and am convinced their example of an RC-not-US space is valid.

Nonetheless, the example is somewhat involved, as more structure was desired by the authors (this space is semi-Hausdorff, Brown, strongly rigid, etc.). After some attempts to "strip down" the example to get a "clean" example of an RC-not-US space, I came up short.

Can anyone construct an "elementary" example of an RC-not-US space?

Comment: @TarasBanakh The question above is related to your paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple example.

Note first that by continuity, if $r\colon X\to A$ is a retraction, and $a_\alpha\in A$ is a net converging to $x$, then $a_\alpha=r(a_\alpha)\to r(x)$, so if $a_\alpha$ has a  ***unique*** limit then $x=r(x)\in A$.

With this in mind, let $X=[0,\infty)\cup \{\infty_1,\infty_2\}.$

The topology on $[0,\infty)$ is the usual Euclidean topology, a neighborhood base of   $\infty_1$ is given by sets of the form $\{\infty_1\}\cup (a,\infty)\backslash 2\mathbb N$, and a base for $\infty_2$ by sets of the form $\{\infty_2\}\cup (a,\infty)\backslash (2\mathbb N +1)$.

Then $X$ is not **US**, since for example the sequence $.5+n$ converges to $\infty_1$ and $\infty_2$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is a retract of $X$, and $a_\alpha\in A$ is a net converging to $x\in [0,\infty)$, then $x$ is the unique limit (as $[0,\infty)$ is Hausdorff), so $x\in A$.  Thus $\overline{A}\cap [0,\infty)=A\cap [0,\infty)$.

Suppose now that $\infty_1\in \overline{A}$. Then either $\infty_1\in A$, or $A$ contains an unbounded subset of $[0,\infty)$.

In the latter case, since $X$ is connected, the retract $A$ is connected, so $A\supseteq [a,\infty)$ for some $a$.  Therefore the sequence $2n+1$ eventually lies in $A$, so since $2n+1$ has a unique limit of $\infty_1$, we again have $\infty_1\in A$.

The same argument applies to $\infty_2$ via the sequence $2n$, and so the retract $A$ is closed.

Thus $X$ is **RC**.

Comment: Nice! I'd tried similar constructions using $\omega$ instead of $[0,\infty)$, but connectedness is quite important in this argument.

Comment: @StevenClontz I started similar to you I think, with three copies of $\omega$, sharing two endpoints. When that didn't work I started connecting dots with segments and eventually got to the final version here.

Comment: Ha! I remember trying the same things. I'm glad you stuck with it a little longer.