# Is the class of rc-spaces closed under products?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. A *retraction* is a continuous map $r:X\to X$ such that $r$ is the identity on $\text{im}(r)$. We call $S\subseteq X$ a *retract* of $X$ if there is a retraction $r:X\to X$ such that $\text{im}(r) = S$.

We say that $(X,\tau)$ is rc if all retracts are closed. It turns out that all Hausdorff spaces have this property.

Is the class of rc-spaces closed under topological products?

Comment: I think https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191016/ shows the answer is no: There are RC spaces that aren't T2, and Bauer showed that any RC space that is preserved by a finite product is T2.

Comment: Thanks @stevenclontz , this escaped me. You can post this as an answer if you want, I'll upvote and accept. Or I'll delete the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X$ to be an [RC space which isn't $T_2$](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=rc%2B%7E%24T_2%24) such as the [one-point compactification of the rationals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000029). We will show $X^2$ is not RC. Note that it is not $T_2$ as its factors are not $T_2$.

First we will note that the diagonal $\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in X\}\subseteq X^2$ is a retract: send $\langle x,y\rangle \mapsto_f \langle x,x\rangle$. This is the composition of the (continuous) projection map onto the first coordinate and the (homeomorphic) map $x\mapsto \langle x,x\rangle$, and thus continuous. Since this map restricted to the diagonal is the identity, it is a retraction.

As noted in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191020), a non-$T_2$ space has a non-closed diagonal: choose $x\not=y$ for which no open neighborhoods are disjoint. Then any basic neighborhood $U\times V$ of $\langle x,y\rangle$ must have $z\in U\cap V$ and therefore $\langle z,z\rangle\in U\times V$, showing $\langle x,y\rangle$ is a limit point of the diagonal.

Thus the diagonal is a retract of $X^2$ which is not closed, showing $X^2$ is not $RC$.

Comment: Very clear writing - thanks a lot, Steven!